# Integral , polynomials and exponential : closed-form formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I would like to calculate an integral under the following form : $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{(t-t_1)e^{at+bt^2}dt}$$

where $0<t_1<t_2$, and $(a,b)\in \mathbb{R^2}$.

I made unfruitful researches on this type of integral, hence I ask your help. Thanks.

Comment: The integral can be expressed in terms of exponential and  [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function).

Answer (score 0):

If $a=0$ or $b=0$ trivial. Assume $a\ne0\ne b$. Completing the square in the exponential exponent polynomial we get $t^2+\frac{a}{b}t+\frac{a^2}{4b^2}-\frac{a^2}{4b^2}=\left(t-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2-\frac{a^2}{4b^2}$. So that $\exp\left(bt^2+at\right)=k\exp \left[b\left(t-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2\right]$, where $k=\exp \left[b\left(-\frac{a^2}{4b^2}\right)\right]$. Now if $t_1=\frac{a}{2b}$, then the we have a trivial case. If not, add and subtract $\frac{a}{2b}$ in the linear polynomial; i.e., $t-t_1=t-t_1+\frac{a}{2b}-\frac{a}{2b}=t-\frac{a}{2b}+C$, where $C=t_1+\frac{a}{2b}$. Thus,
\begin{align}
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\left(t-t_1\right) \exp\left(bt^2+at\right)}dt=k\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\left(t-\frac{a}{2b}\right) \exp \left[b\left(t-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2\right]}dt:=I_1
\\
-k\cdot C\int_{t_1}^{t_2}{\exp \left[b\left(t-\frac{a}{2b}\right)^2\right]}dt:=I_2
\end{align} 
$I_1$ is trivial to evaluate. The value of $I_2$ doesn't have a closed form if $b>0$. If $b<0$ then transform the integral to be defined on $(0,\infty)$ and then use Gamma function.